# Fetch the Lead Owner name on the Cloudpage using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript

I'm working on the Contact Us page, I want to fetch the lead owner from the Lead table on the cloud page. When i am trying to fetch the Lead Owner its show me 500 internal Error.

```
SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead", "Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,AnnualRevenue,MobilePhone,Company,LeadScore__c,RequestedCallBack__c,PreferredTime__c,IndustrySector__c,**Owner**","Id", "=", @contactId)

IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN
  SET @row = row(@subscriberRows,1)
  SET @FirstName = field(@row,"FirstName")
  SET @LastName = field(@row,"LastName")
  SET @Email = field(@row,"Email")
  SET @Company = field(@row,"Company")
  SET @Turnover = field(@row,"AnnualRevenue")
  SET @Mobile = field(@row,"MobilePhone")
  SET @IndustrySector = field(@row,"IndustrySector__c")
  SET @LeadScore = field(@row,"LeadScore__c")
  SET @PreferredTime = field(@row,"PreferredTime__c")
  SET @Industry_Sector = field(@row,"IndustrySector__c")
  **SET @RM_Name= field(@row,"Owner")**

ENDIF
```

Comment: 1) Use a try catch around it to get a meaningful error message: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307474/can-i-retrieve-related-data-using-retrievesalesforceobjects/307486#307486
2) `Owner` is not a field on Lead, you probably want `OwnerId` (Retrieve works with API Names, as you rightly do in the rest of your script.), and that returns the 18 digit ID of the owner. The owner is technically a record on the `User` object, so you could then use the retrieved ID for a retrieve on the `User` object in case you need the name or other info.

Comment: you could also try this code in content builder and do a send preview to perhaps surface the issue

Comment: @JonasLamberty - I am completely new to CRM side. How can I get the specific Owner name using the retrieve OwnerID? If can help with code, that would be great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our last comments.

You want to understand the SFSC data model. Have someone show you Schema builder in SFSC Setup to understand the relationships between tables.
Also make sure you understand what a Lookup relationship is in Sales Cloud.

A Lead has an Owner, and ownership is held by a User.

The name of a Lead Owner is thus something you need to get from the User object as this is where it is stored in SFSC.

So the first part of your retrieve code is all correct, but you can only get the OwnerId off the Lead Object.
Nothing else about the User owning the Lead is physically represented there, - after all, why would we put it there, it can be found on the user once we have the user's unique ID. That's how a relational system works.

With the OwnerId from your first retrieve, you write a second retrieve on the User object, and get the relevant fields from there, in my example I used firstname and lastname.

code is from memory ("should work"), you get the idea:

```
%%[
SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead", "Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,AnnualRevenue,MobilePhone,Company,LeadScore__c,RequestedCallBack__c,PreferredTime__c,IndustrySector__c,OwnerID","Id", "=", @contactId)

IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN
  SET @row = row(@subscriberRows,1)
  SET @FirstName = field(@row,"FirstName")
  SET @LastName = field(@row,"LastName")
  SET @Email = field(@row,"Email")
  SET @Company = field(@row,"Company")
  SET @Turnover = field(@row,"AnnualRevenue")
  SET @Mobile = field(@row,"MobilePhone")
  SET @IndustrySector = field(@row,"IndustrySector__c")
  SET @LeadScore = field(@row,"LeadScore__c")
  SET @PreferredTime = field(@row,"PreferredTime__c")
  SET @Industry_Sector = field(@row,"IndustrySector__c")
  SET @ownerId= field(@row,"OwnerId")

  SET @userRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("User","Id,FirstName,LastName","Id", "=", @ownerId)
    IF RowCount(@userRows) > 0 THEN
        SET @row = row(@userRows,1)
        SET @firstname = field(@row,"FirstName")
        SET @lastname = field(@row,"LastName")
        SET @ownerName = concat(@firstname," ",@lastname)
    ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%%%=v(@ownerName)=%%
```

Be advised that this chaining of retrieves into Sales Cloud can be slow, each one takes a couple seconds. So make sure you test this and ensure that the load time doesn't pose problems.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonas Lamberty for sharing the valuable knowledge and detailed explanation. The above code worked for me. Thank you once again!!